# Linker Error C++ vtable

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I am trying to define an explicit constructor in c++ but im getting thrown a linker error with vtable.

This is what i have so far

```
class Sphere : public Circular{
public:
    Sphere(double r);
    string name() const {return "Sphere";}
    double volume() const;
    double surface_area() const;
};

Sphere:: Sphere(double r): Circular(r){}
```

This is what the error gives me:

```
  "vtable for Sphere", referenced from:
  Sphere::Sphere(double) in main.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
```

But if I do it inline like this:

```
class Sphere : public Circular{
public:
    Sphere(double r):Circular(r){} <--
    string name() const {return "Sphere";}
    double volume() const;
    double surface_area() const;
};
```

Then it doesnt throw any errors. 
Here is my Circular class and GeometricSolid class for reference:

```
class GeometricSolid{
public:
    virtual string name() const = 0;
    virtual double volume() const = 0;
    virtual double surface_area() const = 0;
    virtual ~GeometricSolid(){};
};
class Circular : public GeometricSolid{
protected:
    double radius;
public:
    virtual string name() const = 0;
    virtual double volume() const = 0;
    virtual  double surface_area() const =0;
    Circular(double r);

};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in your `Sphere` class, the functions `volume()` and `surface_area()` remain undefined.
Therefore the compiler doesn't issue any vtable for the Sphere class.

If you want to keep Sphere abstract, define it as such:

```
class Sphere : public Circular{
public:
    Sphere(double r);
    string name() const {return "Sphere";}
    virtual double volume() const = 0;
    virtual double surface_area() const = 0;
};

Sphere::Sphere(double r): Circular(r){}
```

Otherwise provide a definition for these functions.

The reason behind that is that the `vptr` (virtual pointers) in the `vtable` must point to somewhere.

Comment: So by making the Sphere functions a pure virtual I can do a out of line constructor call? But if my function are pure how would the inheritance play out? Wouldnt that mean that in main if we call the volume function on sphere where would it point to? the base class or the derived class? I am just making sure I fully understand why we can do this.